# Why include equality in FOL for ZFC?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, foundations

What are the pros and cons of working with first-order logic with equality for constructing ZFC, when all you have to do is make '$x=y$' a shorthand for:
$$'\forall z [z \in x \Leftrightarrow z \in y] \land \forall w [x \in w \Leftrightarrow y \in w]'$$

Comment: I feel like this is not quite a replacement for logical equality -- in "ordinary" ZFC you would like to be able to conclude $\forall w [x \in w \Leftrightarrow y \in w]$ *from* $\forall z [z \in x \Leftrightarrow z \in y]$. It seems that you are not able to do this from this. (I think, instead, you'd want to define equality as only the first of the conjuncts, and then add an axiom stating that the first conjunct implies the second.)

Comment: How else do you determine if two sets are equal (the same) if not by looking at their respective elements?

Answer (score 1):

There are two "flavours" of *first-order* logic: with and without *equality*.

In the first case (with), the *equality* symbol is considered a *logical* symbol, i.e. we cannot "interpret" it in different ways according to the context (like the conncetive and the quantifiers).

In the second one (without) the *equality* symbol is considered a "mathematical" symbol, like $+$ for f-o arithmetic, and thus (in principle) may be interpreted in different ways according to the context.

---

If we chose to develop set theory in f-o language **without** *equality*, we have to expand the "basic" language with the new (binary) *predicate* symbol $=$ defined by:

> $(x=y) ↔ ∀z(z∈x ↔ z∈y)$.

Comment: So, you're saying that we use FOL with equality to prohibit people from giving interpretations to '=', at least in the case of ZFC?

Comment: @Constantine - more generally, we use FOL with equality because, for the purpose of formalising mathematics, it’s natural to interpret the symbol $=$ by actual equality on the *domain* of the structure we are using to interpret the language.

Comment: Is your definition of "$=$" enough? Or do you also need "$\land \forall z ( x \in z \leftrightarrow y \in z )$"?